# Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)?

Tags: terminal, macos, bash, homebrew, java

this error comes when i use this command:-

> sudo apt install wireless-tools
>   Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)

echo path gives an output like this :-

> /usr/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

don't know what to do ? just a fresher in OS.

Comment: How are you using `apt` on macOS?

Comment: i don;t know saw the command on website to install wireless tools.

Comment: i have installed all :- brew,git,macport,fink,command line tools(xcode)....... There are similar offerings to apt-get for OS X but all of them have to be installed before you can then use them to install packages.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the wireless tools?

Comment: trying to use aircrack.

Comment: Apt has apparently long been removed from Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46812650/why-doesnt-the-annotation-processing-tool-apt-not-operate-after-installing-ja

Answer (score 1):

To install AirCrack (as the author has indicated is his intent), you can either use [MacPorts](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack#installing_on_mac_osx), [Brew](http://brewformulas.org/AircrackNg), or [build from the source.](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack#installing_on_mac_osx)

[Apt, Yum, Pacman, and other package managers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80711/how-to-install-apt-get-or-yum-on-mac-os-x) do not exist on macOS; the closest you'll get is MacPorts or Brew.

Comment: i don't know how to use aircrack, i have already installed it through macport.

Comment: Now I'm really confused. What's the issue then?

Comment: issue is to start airmon-ng it says command not found and i don't know how to use aircrack.

Comment: That's an entirely different issue from what your question asked. I'd recommend posting a different question and I'll work from there.

Comment: already did, check it.